# PuTTY not showing some UTF-8 characters

Tags: putty, unicode, font

So many questions and answers about PuTTY and UTF-8 encoding...

Let me summarize: I'm using a patched Nerd Font (https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts). It displays fine for *most* special characters, but some just don't display correctly in PuTTY. They display fine via Windows Terminal, Notepad etc.

PuTTY (first symbol wrong, second ok):
[image]

Windows Terminal (both symbols correct):
[image]

Windows Charmap (look at the unicode):
[image]

As you can see unicode `0xF0E7` should be a flash-symbol, but PuTTY somehow displays a gothic character. Also when I copy&paste the character from the PuTTY window it *is* the `þ`, not the flash-icon. Somehow PuTTY changed the unicode codepoint? þ is 0x00FE not 0xF0E7!
Also note that PuTTY does display other special characters just fine like the folder-symbol or the heart-symbol in the screenshots.

### My settings:

#### Putty

- Window > Appearance > Font: Some Nerdfont & Allow selection of variable-pitch fonts
- Window > Appearance > Font Quality: ClearType
- Window > Translation > Remote charset: UTF-8
- Window > Translation > Drawing Characters: Use Unicode line drawings

#### Bash

- `locale` returns `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` (as well as `LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8`)

#### TMUX

- `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`
- `setw -q -g utf8 on`

When I ssh into the box via Windows Terminal everything is working as expected, also via tmux. Only when I use PuTTY some UTF-8 characters are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is an good solution with DejaVu.
Download and install DejaVu (https://github.com/dejavu-fonts/dejavu-fonts)
In putty under "Apperance" "Font settings" select "DejaVu Sans Mono, 10tp regular".
Then it will work.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/393834/how-to-configure-putty-to-display-these-characters

Comment: I'm using a patched font already as stated in the OP.